# Get document's name with it's description

Tags: vba, ms-word

Trying to get the name of the active window with it's description, can't find any method.

My problem is that while I can access document's file name with `Document.Name`, I can't get the commentaries that Word attaches to it, like (Compatibility Mode, Last modified by User etc), without them, the method `Windows(Document.Name)` doesn't work, is there any solution for this?

My program opens four new documents and switches in a loop the active document, taking information from the original and putting some excerpts in the new ones.

Everything works when there is no commentaries for documents, but as they appear, program breaks, saying:

> 5941 The requested member of the collection does not exist

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I think you should use different functions to get that info. For example to get the file created or last modified date time you should use: `FileDateTime("C:\instructions.doc")`
`Result: '6/1/2004 7:40:18 PM'`

Comment: If Right(ActiveDocument.Name, 1) = "c" then the document has been opene in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
Windows(1).Document
```

will give you the document associated with a window. (You may need to loop through the windows to find the one you're interested in.)

Once you have the document you can access its properties:

```
Windows(1).Document.CompatibilityMode
```

Hope that helps